# Calculating a daily mean in R

Tags: r

Say I have the following matrix:

```
x1 = 1:288
x2 = matrix(x1,nrow=96,ncol=3)
```

Is there an easy way to get the mean of rows 1:24,25:48,49:72,73:96 for column 2?

Basically I have a one year time series and I have to average some data every 24 hours.

Answer (score 10):

There is.

Suppose we have the days :

```
Days <- rep(1:4,each=24)
```

you could do easily

```
tapply(x2[,2],Days,mean)
```

If you have a dataframe with a Date variable, you can use that one. You can do that for all variables at once, using aggregate :

```
x2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x2,Days))
aggregate(x2[,1:3],by=list(Days),mean)
```

Take a look at the help files of these functions to start with. Also do a search here, there are quite some other interesting answers on this problem :

- [Aggregating daily content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620569/r-aggregating-daily-content)
- [Compute means of a group by factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858461/compute-means-of-a-group-by-factor)

PS : If you're going to do a lot of timeseries, you should take a look at the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo.pdf) package (on CRAN : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html )

Comment: @SnowFrog You're wrong. tapply doesn't create a data frame. It creates a vector (in this case). Big difference.

Comment: One issue with the `tapply` method is that it creates a vector (number of columns = number of days). The `aggregate` method creates a data frame (1 column with number of rows = number of days), which may be more practical if subsequent manipulation of the data is needed.

Comment: for reference to others: if you haven't created an independent object for Days, and it's only a column in your df, for aggregate() you'll need to specify df$Days

Answer (score 6):

**1) ts.** Since this is a regularly spaced time series, convert it to a `ts` series and then aggregate it from frequency 24 to frequency 1:

```
aggregate(ts(x2[, 2], freq = 24), 1, mean)
```

giving:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1
End = 4
Frequency = 1
[1] 108.5 132.5 156.5 180.5
```

**2) zoo.** Here it is using zoo.  The zoo package can also handle irregularly spaced series (if we needed to extend this). Below `day.hour` is the day number (1, 2, 3, 4) plus the hour as a fraction of the day so that `floor(day.hour)` is just the day number:

```
library(zoo)

day.hour <- seq(1, length = length(x2[, 2]), by = 1/24)
z <- zoo(x2[, 2], day.hour)
aggregate(z, floor, mean)
##          1     2     3     4 
##      108.5 132.5 156.5 180.5
```

If `zz` is the output from `aggregate` then `coredata(zz)` and `time(zz)` are the values and times, respectively, as ordinary vectors.

Comment: +1 for showing how to use zoo and ts for that. I didn't mention it as I didn't want to assume too much about the data in the real problem, but it is definitely relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Quite compact and computationally fast way of doing this is to reshape the vector into a suitable matrix and calculating the column means.

```
colMeans(matrix(x2[,2],nrow=24))
```

Comment: clean solution, provided that there is no missing data anywhere. Otherwise the matrix wouldn't represent the days.

Comment: You do need to be careful with this method so that the dimensions are right. But you can deal with missing data by using NA for those and using na.rm=TRUE

Comment: I am aware of that :-) I means missing in the sense of "not every day has 24 rows of data"